# how to redefine preprocessor directives of c++ libraries in an c++ application program

Tags: c++

I give the following example to illustrate my question. Suppose now I am creating a c++ library, and the head file and its implementation file are as follows:

```
// head.h
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{

    public:
          int obtain_value();

};

// head.cpp
 int MyClass::obtain_value()
{
  #ifndef DEFINE_FIVE
     return 6;
  #else
     return 5;
  #endif

}
```

In this library, if I define `DEFINE_FIVE` when compiling the library, I will obtain 5 when invoking `obtain_value` function; otherwise, I will obtain 6. Let's assume that when I compiled the library, I did not define `DEFINE_FIVE`. In the c++ program that will call this library, when voking `obtain_value` function, we expect to have 6. Then my question is, what can I do in the C++ program that invokes the library so that the output of calling this function will be 5. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing. Library is already compiled. You will receive `6` anyway, until you recompile the library with DEFINE_FIVE.

Comment: You can't. Your library contains no trace of 5. If you want 5, you need to build a different library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessor directives are evaluated at compile time, you cannot change the code in runtime.
If you compile the library and DEFINE_FIVE is not defined, the preprocessor will in first pass replace your code to the following:

```
// head.cpp
int MyClass::obtain_value()
{
     return 6;    
}
```

As you can see, it will parse and remove all preprocessor directives. Then, the real compiling stage starts with machine code generation.

If you want dynamic values in your library, you have to change your interface, for example:

```
// head.h
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{

    public:
          int obtain_value(bool give_me_five=false);

};

// head.cpp
 int MyClass::obtain_value(bool give_me_five)
{
     if (!give_me_five)
        return 6;
     else return 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `/D` switch in visual studio to define `DEFINE_FIVE` and you will get your desired result.

```
goto properties --> C/C++ --> preprocessor --> preprocessor definations --> DEFINE_FIVE
```

the during compile time `DEFINE_FIVE` will be defined and you will get `return 5`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are perhaps a bit pessimistic. You can create a replacement DLL, which [forwards](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060719-24/?p=30473/) every function to the original DLL *except* `int MyClass::obtain_value()`, for which you provide a new implementation.

Downside: direct calls to `obtain_value` from inside the class won't go through the replacement DLL, which can lead to hard-to-debug errors. This is because you will have two copies of `int MyClass::obtain_value()` from two DLLs in one process.